# How to access a spring-mvc flash redirectAttribute in the filter chain before the DispatcherServlet is invoked?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, redirect, post-redirect-get

I have the following controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/my-account")
public class AccountController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/foo/post",
            method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doPost(final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flashAttribute", "flashAttributeValue");
        return "redirect:/my-account/foo/get";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/foo/get",
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final Model model) {
        System.out.println("in request: " + RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request).get("flashAttribute"));
        System.out.println("in model: " + model.asMap().get("flashAttribute"));
    }
}
```

I would also like to access the flash attribute `flashAttribute` during the invocation of a filter in the filter chain that finally invokes springs default `DispatcherServlet` which in turn invokes `AccountController`.

```
public class FlashAttributeBasedFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String flashAttribute = // how to access the redirectAttribute flashAttribute here?
        // do something with flashAttribute ...

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

The `DispatcherServlet` uses a `org.springframework.web.servlet.FlashMapManager` that handles these flash attributes, but it doesn't provide read-only access so I think I would be messing something up if I would use it in the filter. And also the `FlashMapManager` instance is kept in the dispatcher servlet privately.

Does anybody have an idea how I can make the redirect attribute accessible in the filter chain for the `GET` request succeeding the `POST`?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution for the same problem! If I find something I'll write.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that all these methods return `null` into my filter (I don't understand why):

```
RequestContextUtils.getFlashMapManager(httpRequest)
RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(httpRequest)
RequestContextUtils.getOutputFlashMap(httpRequest)
```

I used a drastic solution: read directly the into the session (where flash attributes are stored).

```
CopyOnWriteArrayList<FlashMap> what = (CopyOnWriteArrayList<FlashMap>) httpRequest.getSession().getAttribute("org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager.FLASH_MAPS");
if (what != null) {
    FlashMap flashMap = what.get(0);
    [read flashMap as you read a HashMap]
}
```

I know, this code is super ugly but at the moment I don't find another solution.

Comment: Using `RequestContextUtils` will only provide results when the `DispatcherServlet` applied its `FlashMapManager` to the request. The problem with using `what.get(0)` is that this may fail if there are multiple pending redirects for the same http session.

Comment: The code worked like a charm. Who cares if it's super ugly? :)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, following works for me.

FlashMap flashMap = new SessionFlashMapManager().retrieveAndUpdate(request, null);
flashMap.get("parameter");